if then statement only acting on first instance of matching string
I am missing some knowledge here and I don't have the proper language to describe (sorry for that). This is my command which is only returning the first instance when it finds a match in "$WARN"
echo "$WARN"

(W) 2024-08-30T08:08:52 - Restart is required to toggle support
(W) 2024-08-30T09:59:30 - Failed to download RSS feed at 'https://aaa'. Reason: The connection to the remote server timed out
(W) 2024-08-30T10:00:30 - Failed to download RSS feed at 'https://bbb'. Reason: The connection to the remote server timed out
(W) 2024-08-30T10:00:30 - Failed to download RSS feed at 'https://ccc'. Reason: The connection to the remote server timed out
(W) 2024-09-13T08:59:44 - Failed to download RSS feed at 'http://xxx'. Reason: The remote server refused the connection
(W) 2024-09-13T08:59:44 - Failed to download RSS feed at 'http://yyy'. Reason: The remote server refused the connection
(W) 2024-09-13T08:59:44 - Failed to download RSS feed at 'http://zzz'. Reason: The remote server refused the connection

WARN=$(
  if [[ "$WARN" == *Failed* ]]
  then
  printf '%s' "${WARN//''\'*''\'\./...}"
  fi
)

echo "$WARN"

(W) 2024-08-30T08:08:52 - Restart is required to toggle support
(W) 2024-08-30T09:59:30 - Failed to download RSS feed at ... Reason: The connection to the remote server timed out


expected output: unique lines and lines that match "Failed" are modified to remove everything inside single quotes including the quotes themselves.
(W) 2024-08-30T08:08:52 - Restart is required to toggle support
(W) 2024-08-30T09:59:30 - Failed to download RSS feed at ... Reason: The connection to the remote server timed out
(W) 2024-09-13T08:59:44 - Failed to download RSS feed at ... Reason: The remote server refused the connection

actual output: why is the second line omitted from consideration, i.e. only the first matching line containing Failed is acted on and returned.
echo "$WARN"

(W) 2024-08-30T08:08:52 - Restart is required to toggle support
(W) 2024-08-30T09:59:30 - Failed to download RSS feed at ... Reason: The connection to the remote server timed out

If I sort the input so it is reversed the second matching occurrence of Failed is omitted.
echo "$WARN"

(W) 2024-09-13T08:59:44 - Failed to download RSS feed at ... Reason: The remote server refused the connection
(W) 2024-08-30T08:08:52 - Restart is required to toggle support

I don't want to match on the end of the strings.
I am replacing the var $WARN with new content the second time I create it.

Initially the WARN variable contains multiple lines. Still, like any non-array shell variable it's just a single string and the fact there are newline characters inside does not change this.
[[ "$WARN" == *Failed* ]] tests if there is a substring Failed anywhere inside the string. It's one test acting on the entire string, not "per line".
Similarly the substitution in ${WARN//\'*\'./...} (for brevity I removed the unnecessary backslash and two pairs of single-quotes that embraced an empty string each) acts on the entire string at once, not "per line"; and because * is greedy then there is a match that starts inside the first "failed" line and ends at the last "failed" line. In other words the match includes several single-quotes and several newline characters, all this is replaced by ....
In yet other words: the line with ... you saw in the output consists of the beginning of some line, the ... and the end of a different line.
Use a tool that processes one line at a time, e.g. sed:
<<<"$WARN" sed "/Failed/ s/'.*'\\./.../"

Note .* in '.*' is greedy, it can match a string containing ' (or even a newline character); but now there is no problem because our sed processes each line separately.
You can filter out "similar" lines by piping to uniq:
<<<"$WARN" sed "/Failed/ s/'.*'\\./.../" | uniq -f 3

uniq -f 3 ignores the first three fields, which are (W), the timestamp and - in your case. This way different timestamps do not prevent lines from being considered equal, only the content that follows matters. It seems this is what you want.
More complex logic can be implemented e.g. with awk.
Maybe you can do it without the variable. If the value of the variable came from the output of some_tool then this may be enough:
some_tool | sed "/Failed/ s/'.*'\\./.../" | uniq -f 3

If the value of the variable came from a_file then this may be enough:
<a_file sed "/Failed/ s/'.*'\\./.../" | uniq -f 3


Thank you for the detailed explanation!! Regarding your replacement for my substitution... it doesn't work on my system. It only works formatted this way: ${WARN//''\'*''\'\./...} ShellCheck
